# c++ pass dynamically allocated 2d vector to function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, 2d-vector

I'm trying to pass a dynamically allocated 2d vector to a function by reference in c++.

Originally I was trying to do this with a 2d array, but I was told to try with a 2d vector instead. My code below is failing at the solve_point(boardExVector) line due to a conversion error.

```html
#include <stdio.h>       /* printf */
#include <bits/stdc++.h> /* vector of strings */
using namespace std;

void solve_point(vector<char> *board){ 
    printf("solve_point\n");
    board[2][2] = 'c';
}

int main(){
    //dynamically allocate width and height
    int width = 7;
    int height = 9;
    //create 2d vector
    vector<vector<char>> boardExVector(width, vector<char>(height));
    boardExVector[1][2] = 'k';
    //pass to function by reference
    solve_point(boardExVector);
    //err: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>>>" to "std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>> *" exists
    printf("board[2][2] = %c\n", boardExVector[2][2]);
}
```

I'm just getting back into c++ so pointers and references are something I'm working on getting better at, I've looked for solutions to this online and have tried some already which usually involve changing the solve_point function header to include a * or & but I haven't gotten it to work yet. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `solve_point` expects a `vector<char>*`, but you're sending a `vector<vector<char>>`. The solution will depend on what you want `solve_point` to do.

Comment: But in general, use `&` for passing by reference. You only need to use `*` to pass by 'reference' if `nullptr` is a possible value of the thing you're passing in.

Comment: Change the argument of `solve_point()` to be `vector<vector<char> > &board`.

Comment: One of the answers to that other question already shows exactly how to declare `solve_point` for `vector<vector<char>>`. You need to at least explain why that answer isn't sufficient, or you'll just get the same one again. Slow down and read the types, the error messages _and that answer_ carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function argument expects a pointer to a vector of `char` type, while the caller function is passing a vector of `vector<char>` type. Are you looking for the following changes in your function?

```
//bits/stdc++.h is not a standard library and must not be included.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> /* vector of strings */
using namespace std;

void solve_point(vector<vector <char>> &board){
    printf("solve_point\n");
    board[2][2] = 'c';
}

int main(){
    //dynamically allocate width and height
    int width = 7;
    int height = 9;
    //create 2d vector
    vector<vector<char>> boardExVector(width, vector<char>(height));
    boardExVector[1][2] = 'k';
    //pass to function by reference
    solve_point(boardExVector);
    //err: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>>>" to "std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>> *" exists
    printf("board[2][2] = %c\n", boardExVector[2][2]);
}
```